# Ansible : How to union two dicts

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have two dicts :

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ policies_json.working_dir }}"

{'raw': ['gore', 'logs'], 'stg': ['gore', 'logs'], 'itl': ['gore', 'logs'], 'biz': ['gore', 'logs']}

- debug:
    msg: "{{ new_project_working_dirs }}"

{'raw': ['output', 'input'], 'biz': ['cars', 'bus']}
```

I want to merge these two dicts to have this result :

```
{'raw': ['gore', 'logs', 'output', 'input'], 'stg': ['gore', 'logs'], 'itl': ['gore', 'logs'], 'biz': ['gore', 'logs', 'cars', 'bus']}
```

I tried this, but it override values

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ policies_json.working_dir | combine(new_project_working_dirs) }}"
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries

Comment: _If `list_merge='append'`, arrays from the right hash will be appended to the ones in the left hash:_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5) stated in the above comment.

> If list_merge='append', arrays from the right hash will be appended to the ones in the left hash:

By  adding `list_merge='append'` to combine function fixed my issue.